# How to make a program restart after an error forces it to stop?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-3.x, restart

In Python I often use try-except blocks to except certain conditions.  However, unexpected errors could potentially be raised and I can't account for all of them.  How would I go about restarting a Python program when it stops running inside of an environment such as Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch `BaseException` class. It is the basic class for all errors so you will process them all.

If you want keep program running when smth really nasty happens, like memory leak or segmentation fault, you should write a watchdog. Watchdog is a program that checks process with specified pid running and if not, restarts it.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your python code in an infinite while loop in the shell:

```
$ while :
do
python -c '1 + []'
done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

You could easily do the same thing for a python script:

```
$ while :
do
python mycode.py
done
```